# timeout vs pause in TeraTerm (ttl) script

Tags: teraterm

I came across a few scripts which uses `timeout = 5` and a few other scripts which uses `pause 5` to add a delay of 5 seconds. I would like to know and understand the difference between these two flavors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timeout is used generally with wait* commands. Wait* commands wait for the specific input until the 'timeout' seconds. Wait will return early with success, if it receives required input.

Pause is mandatory pause in the execution. Pause stops the execution of the script for specified seconds.

Comment: In practice, we could use wait and pause in the same script when we need different lengths of waiting time.